# Attachments in phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, attachment

I cant seem to figure out the follow:

- How to make the attached file only be a specific file (example: only
  a .jpg file can be attached).
- Limit the file size
- After the file is sent, it gets deleted from the server

  ```
  <div class="white-jumbotron">
    <div class="container">

  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required />
      <p class='text-danger'></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required />
      <p class='text-danger'></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" required />
      <p class='text-danger'></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Resume upload</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file">
      <br /> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-green" />
  </div>
  </form>

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $emailAddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
   require "class.phpmailer.php";
   $msg = 'First Name:'.$_POST['firstName'].'<br /> Last name:'.$_POST['lastName'].'<br /> Email:'.$_POST['email'].'<br />';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsMail();

    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->Subject = "Subject";
    $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
    $mail->Send();

    echo'<script> window.location="../careers-sent.php"; </script> ';
  }
  ?>

    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: what you have tried so far ? for your three criteria ?

Comment: Base your code on [the upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps), and [use the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Be wary of embedding post variables directly in your message -- if someone enters a big blob of HTML code in the `firstName` field then you'll get an email that looks quite different from what you're expecting. You should do some basic sanity checks on those fields.

Comment: Also, you probably don't need to move the uploaded file if all you're going to do is send it in the email and discard it. You only need to use `move_uploaded_file()` if you intend to keep the file on your server. If you don't need to keep it, you can simply reference the `tmp_name` when doing `AddAttachment()`.

Comment: Finally, move the PHP code to the top of your program, so it is above the HTML code. Then you will be able to use a better redirect method (ie `header('Location:...')` rather than a javascript redirect).

Comment: @Simba Would you be able to draft a quick secure contact form with an attachment. You seem to know what your doing.

Comment: Hi. Sadly, I won't have time for that. However, I think there is enough advice here from myself and others for you to succeed. And be happy: you're using phpMailer, so you're already way more secure than all the other newbies who are trying to use PHP's built-in `mail()` function.

Comment: @Simba okay thank you for your help/advice. I will look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, split the view (<div...) and the processing (<?php...) in two different files to avoid sending again the mail when the user presses F5.

1) In the processing, put a condition on the filename

```
if (preg_match("/\\.jpg$/",$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]))
{
    //OK
}
else
{
    //KO, redirect to error page
}
```

2) Can't test here but I suppose there can also be a "size" attibute of the file

3) Put a check on the send

```
if ($mail->send())
{
    unlink($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
}
else
{
    //KO, log to debug file
}
```

EDIT : code integration

view.php (rename at convenience)

```
<div class="white-jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

  <form action="" method="post" action="val_mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required />
        <p class='text-danger'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required />
         <p class='text-danger'></p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" required />
        <p class='text-danger'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Resume upload</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file">
        <br /> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-green" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

val_mail.php (rename at convenience but match with the above `action` attribute of the form)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!preg_match("/\\.jpg$/",$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]))
  {
    echo'<script> window.location="../error-attachment.php"; </script> '; exit;// create error page
  }
  $emailAddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
  require "class.phpmailer.php";
  $msg = 'First Name:'.$_POST['firstName'].'<br /> Last  name:'.$_POST['lastName'].'<br /> Email:'.$_POST['email'].'<br />';
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],  $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsMail();

  $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
  $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $mail->Subject = "Subject";
  $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
  $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
  if ($mail->Send())
  {
     unlink($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
  }
  else
  {
     echo'<script> window.location="../error-sent.php"; </script> '; exit;// create error page
  }

  echo'<script> window.location="../careers-sent.php"; </script> ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit my code to include what you wrote. I am still learning and a total noob at PHP.

Comment: I cannot edit your code in the question post because I don't know about your development environment so there might be some side effects... Also when SO visitors reach this page, the code in the question must be "false" for them to better understand the context of the answers. You are maybe a noob at PHP but do you have knowledge on general algorithmics (functions, conditions, loops,...) ? If so you can easily adapt my answer to your existing code, thus earning experience.

Comment: I've split the form (html and dive) from the php and added a php include. However I am still confused where to place the code you've provided. I've tried and failed to do so. Once I add you code the file doesn't get attached anymore.

Comment: Implemented and tested. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}
```

example : https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wikis/AdvancedMail.wiki

Comment: Can you include this in the code. I tried to make it fit and its not working for me.